# JavaScript array's length method

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone explain why the second alert says 0 ?

```
  var pollData = new Array();
  pollData['pollType'] = 2;
  alert(pollData['pollType']); // This prints 2
  alert(pollData.length); // This prints 0 ??
```

Comment: that shit cray. don't do that to arrays u make my brain hurt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The length of the array is only changed when you add numeric indexes. For example,

```
pollData["randomString"] = 23;
```

has no effect on length, but

```
var pollData = [];
pollData["45"] = "Hello";
pollData.length; // 46
```

changes the length to 46. Note that it doesn't matter if the key was a number or a string, as long as it is a numeric integer.

Besides, you are not supposed to use arrays in this manner. Consider it more of a side effect, since arrays are objects too, and in JavaScript any object can hold arbitrary keys as strings.

Comment: Can I have the key as the string 'pollType'?

Comment: Yes, you can. The example in your question does exactly that. But it's not a good practice. Do you want to store additional data related to the array somewhere?

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't add them to the array as the length is still 0

Comment: Thank you for this! Made a fiddle, because nobody believed me that it worked this way: http://jsfiddle.net/6WrkT/1/

Comment: I know this is late but wanted to add that creating an array using a constructor also cause this issue.
var pollData = new Array(45);

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't put anything into the array yet. You've only been assigning to a dynamically-created `pollType` attribute on the array *object*.

If you use numeric indices, then the array automagically takes care of length. For example:

```
var arr = [  ];    // same as new Array()
arr[2] = 'Banana!';
alert(arr.length);    // prints 3 (indexes 0 through 2 were created)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `length` property takes into consideration only those members of the array which names are indexes (like `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, ... ).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript have numeric indexes only.

Use an object, which is essentially what you are doing above, setting properties on that array object.

Answer (score 0):

array.length returns how many values are stored in the array. The first alert is returning the value of the position 'pollType'.

The reference guide I always use when needing help with javascript arrays is this page http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays

I'd also read what it says under the heading Javascript Does Not Support Associative Arrays, as you may run into problems with this also.

Comment: Just want to note, that while that's what Array.length supposedly does, it doesn't behave that way. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WrkT/1/

Answer (score 0):

var pollData = Array();

```
function test() {
    pollData[0] = 2
    alert(pollData[0]);
    alert(pollData.length);
}
```

//[x] is the array position; hence ['polltype'] is causing issues